# Creation time of scala object

Tags: scala, object, singleton

In Scala, it's said object is singleton. So I'm wondering what's the creation time of object.

That's I created two scala files as below:

```
object Singleton {
def Singleton() = {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("creation time: " + time)
}
def getTime() = {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("current time: " + time)
}
}

object Test {
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    Singleton.getTime()
    Thread sleep 10000
    Singleton.getTime()
}
}
```

Output is:

`current time: 1415180237062
current time: 1415180247299`

So when is the Singleton object created??

Comment: Scala is not Java. Constructors are not defined by using the name of the class or object as method name.

Comment: You are right, I just changed, and verified it's created when during the first call.

Answer (score 4):

It is much easier to try it in Scala REPL:

```
scala> object Singleton {
     |   println("creation time: " + System.nanoTime())
     |   def getTime = println("current time:  " + System.nanoTime())
     | }
defined module Singleton

scala> def test = {
     |   println("before call:   " + System.nanoTime())
     |   Singleton.getTime
     |   Singleton.getTime
     | }
test: Unit

scala> test
before call:   1194990019328128
creation time: 1194990019677693
current time:  1194990019889606
current time:  1194990020062275
```

Answer (score 3):

A scala `object` behaves like a `lazy val`; it will be instantiated the first time it's referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you rightføld, make some change and verified object just behaved as singleton, and created when first called

```
object Singleton {
  def getTime() = {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("current time: " + time)
  }
  private def init() {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("creation time: " + time)
  }
  init()
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("before call: " + time)
    Singleton.getTime()
    Thread sleep 10000
    Singleton.getTime()
  }
}
```

output is:

```
before call: 1415183199534
creation time: 1415183199732
current time: 1415183199732
current time: 1415183209735
```